# How to add trigger to Updatepanel where the event for trigger is inside a User Control inside Repeater?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, triggers, updatepanel

I have a UserControl called CustomerFinder for searhing customers. And there is "ADD" button inside the repeater. I have created an eventhandler for Repeater_ItemCommand. Because i am going to use it on the other page.

On the other page, i use this User Control which is not in UpdatePanel.
There is an update panel for the Selected Customers(when they click add,customer is selected)

When they click the ADD button which is in the UserControl i want update panel to refresh it self.

[image]
<sub>(source: [barbarosalp.com](http://www.barbarosalp.com/questions/updatePanelcommand.png))</sub>

As you see above Intellisense can get the Event Name "**OnrptCustomersCommand**"

[image]
<sub>(source: [barbarosalp.com](http://www.barbarosalp.com/questions/updatePanelcommand1.png))</sub>

And this is the trigger...

I get an Error "couldnt find the event 'OnrptCustomersComman'"

How can i get it done ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Images in links no longer exist, which I assume to contain code examples, so this question has become unhelpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Micheal Knishkern about his answer.

But i did it work by my way too :)

Just delete two chars "On" from the Event name.

**OnrptCustomersEvent** to **rptCustomersEvent**

Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Remove the `ucCustomerFinder` asyncpostbacktrigger element from the triggers section and add the `pnlSelectedCustomers.Update()` command to the `Repeater_ItemCommand` event of the repeater

Comment: You are right :) I couldnt understand why did i try ultra things for that :). But i did it work by assignin triggers on aspx page.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I recognized it now while i was checking my project, it s not an asyncpostback if i did pnlSelectedCustomer.Update()